# onClick listener not calling JavaScript

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have an onClick listener set to trigger an AJAX call which in turn triggers a PHP script. However, it doesn't seem to recognize the click. Any ideas?

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function doThings(){
    document.write("Test");
    $.ajax( {
    type: "GET",
    url: "script.php",
    success:function(data){
    if(data==0)
        $("#imgId").attr("src","lightbulb_0.png");
    else
        $("#imgId").attr("src","lightbulb_1.png");
    }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="imgId" src="lightbulb_0" onClick='doThings();'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Script.php

```
<?php
function toggle()
{
        $filename = "brightness";
        $otherDirectory="/sys/class/leds/led0/";
        $f = fopen($otherDirectory . $filename,"r");
        $value = fgets($f);
        $newvalue = 1;
        fclose($f);
        if ((int)$value == 1) {
           $newvalue = 0;
        }

        if ((int)$value == 0) {
           $newvalue = 1;
        }

        $f = fopen($otherDirectory . $filename,"w+");

        fwrite($f, $newvalue);

        fclose($f);

        echo $newvalue;

}
toggle();
?>
```

EDIT: Added code on here, and used fix from below. Now the onClick() works, but after setting the image to lightbulb_1, it won't go to 0.

EDIT2: Fixed using combination of all solutions below. Thanks alot!

Comment: Questions should be stand alone and not depend on external sites to be understood, please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) *in the question*.

Comment: Your problem is in the PHP. `newvalue` is nothing, it should be `echo $newvalue`. Please just test your code and check for errors.

Comment: Incidentally, [use a validator](http://validator.w3.org/). At least one significant error is picked up by the HTML 5 validator that the W3C host.

Comment: @putvande: `newvalue` will issue a notice (undefined T_CONSTANT), and PHP will assume you meant to quote the token, using it as a string: `'newvalue'`

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't recognize the click" ? Is the Javascript not run, or is the PHP not called?

Comment: @user3433131 make sure file exist in your location and check file permission for read and write the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Separate `<script>` tag for including `js` files and `code`. Use below code,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doThings(){
    //Your function code
}
</script>

//Html codes
<img id="imgId" src="lightbulb_0" onClick='doThings();'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML / JS is fine (with the edit you made), it is your PHP that has an error in it.
You have `echo newvalue` when it should be `echo $newvalue`:

```
<? php
function toggle() {
    $filename = "brightness";
    $otherDirectory = "/sys/class/leds/led0/";
    $f = fopen($otherDirectory.$filename, "r");
    $value = fgets($f);
    $newvalue = 1;
    fclose($f);
    if ((int) $value == 1) {
        $newvalue = 0;
    }

    if ((int) $value == 0) {
        $newvalue = 1;
    }

    $f = fopen($otherDirectory.$filename, "w+");

    fwrite($f, $newvalue);

    fclose($f);

    echo $newvalue;

}
toggle(); 

?>
```

If that doesn't work, have a look at if your file `brightness` (without an extension?) does exist and your directory path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

inside you ajax call you xud include "dataType" that your php script is returning, example if reurning json you will have above, remeber to json_encode it.

```
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
url: "script.php",
```

if html

```
type: "GET",
dataType: "html",
url: "script.php",
```